# POODLE vulnerabiilty. Giving client warnings if their browser can fall back to SSL 3.0 on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

If we disable SSL 3.0 completely on the server, the customer whose browswer cannot support TLS 1.0 will just show a failed connection to the client browser.

Question 1: How do I detect if the client browser cannot support TLS 1.0 and give him a more intelligent warning that his browswer is out of date, and need to be upgraded.

Question 2: How do I detect if the client browswer can support SSL 3.0 and is vunerable to the POODLE attack, and warn them of this?

I'm using a Microsoft IIS web server and ASP.NET